# Failure to move gzipped file

Tags: bash, gzip, mv

I'm attempting to write a program that moves zipped files that arrive in a directory, unzips them and then outputs the contents.

```
 #!/bin/bash
shopt -s extglob
echo "Press [CTRL+C] to stop.."
#begin loop
while :
do
    #search folder test_source for files and append names to array
    queue+=($(ls /home/ec2-user/glutton/test_source | egrep 'test[0-9]{1}.gz'))
    for i in $queue; do
        #move file in test_source to temp folder
        mv /home/ec2-user/glutton/test_source/${queue[i]} /home/ec2-user/glutton/temp
        #unzip file
        gunzip /home/ec2-user/glutton/temp/${queue[i]}
        #add new file name to variable unzipped
        unzipped=($(ls /home/ec2-user/glutton/temp | egrep 'test[0-9]{1}'))
        cat temp/$unzipped
        #Test for successful run
        exit_status=$?
        if [ $exit_status -eq 1 ]; then
            #If fail move file to bank and output
            mv /home/ec2-user/glutton/temp/$unzipped /home/ec2-user/glutton/logs/bank
            echo "Error! $unzipped moved to /home/ec2-user/glutton/logs/bank"
            #write to error.log
            echo "moved ${queue[i]} to bank due to error" >> /home/ec2-user/glutton/logs/error.log
        else 
            #If success delete file
            rm /home/ec2-user/glutton/temp/$unzipped
        fi
        #wipe variable
        unset unzipped
        i=$i+1
    done
#wipe array
unset queue
i=0
#go to top of loop
done
```

This has worked pretty well up until I added the unzipping feature and now my program outputs this error when attempting to move the `.gz` file:

```
   ./glutton.sh: line 11: test0.gz: syntax error: invalid arithmetic operator (error token is ".gz")
```

When I run the first part of my script in the command line it seems to work perfectly, but doesn't when I run it on its own, I'm pretty confused.

Comment: You may find running the scrip with 'set -x' as the 2nd line may make things like this easier to debug.

Comment: Don't use `ls`: `queue+=( /home/ec2-user/glutton/test_source/test[0-9].gz )` should do what you want. (Even with `grep`, the `{1}` is unnecessary.)

Comment: Run your code through shellcheck.net; there are several problems with it.

Comment: @chepner I’ve run the code through shell checker as suggested by other people in this thread :) cheers for the extra advice though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your main issue is that when you iterate an array like you are doing, you get the first item of the array, not the index. So in your case, $i is not a number, it is the filename (i.e. test1.gz) and it will only see the first file. The cleanest way I have seen to iterate the items in an array would be `for i in "${arrayName[@]}"`.

Also, using '{1}' in your regex is redundant, the character class will already match only 1 character if you don't specify a modifier.

It shouldn't matter depending on the contents of your 'temp' folder, but I would be more specific on your egreps too, if you add `-x` then it will have to match the whole string. As it is currently, a file called 'not_a_test1' would match.

Comment: I found the issue now, i wasn't defining the array properly so i'm now using  for i in ${!queue[@]}; do

Comment: @user3019354 You don't need to though, if you just treated $i as the filename, the code you had worked and is arguably much easier to read.

Comment: after doing some testing with set -x i did realise that i was the filename so i decided to define the variables more clearly, and I've added your suggestions to the regex.

Comment: Cool. 'set -x' has saved me lots of time on many occaisions. Also, if you haven't used it already, shellcheck is an excellent tool for helping write better scripts and catching issues early without having to execute.

Comment: brill! i'll be sure to use shellcheck to fix my code in the future :)

Comment: I edited my answer because I realised what I told you about just leaving it as is and using $i as filename was wrong because you only get the first element of the array.